# Getting error in - (BOOL)copyItemAtURL:(NSURL *)srcURL toURL:(NSURL *)dstURL error:(NSError **)error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager, uidocumentpickervc

I am picking documents from iCloud and google drive etc and using this method `- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url`

I am getting the url `file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/34C6FC23-C8BF-407E-AD67-77758BD606E9/tmp/com.company.theApp-Inbox/chart%20(1).pdf`

but when I am doing this `[[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtURL:url toURL:docUrl error:&error];`

I am getting this error `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=262 "The file couldn’t be opened because the specified URL type isn’t supported." UserInfo={NSURL=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/34C6FC23-C8BF-407E-AD67-77758BD606E9/Documents/documents/12345678901-1470638583.pdf}`

and this is my `docUrl = /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/34C6FC23-C8BF-407E-AD67-77758BD606E9/Documents/documents/12345678901-1470638583.pdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try initialising your `docUrl` with:

```
NSURL *docUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:@"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/34C6FC23-C8BF-407E-AD67-77758BD606E9/Documents/documents/12345678901-1470638583.pdf"];
```

I'm guessing that `copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:` doesn't recognise your URL as a file URL.

Comment: This is what I am doing NSURL *docUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[documentFolderDataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fn]];

Comment: And if you change that to: `NSURL *docUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[documentFolderDataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fn]];`?

Answer (score 0):

In swift world:

```
URL(fileURLWithPath: "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/34C6FC23-C8BF-407E-AD67-77758BD606E9/Documents/documents/12345678901-1470638583.pdf")
```

Answer (score -3):

Please try initialising your docUrl with:

> NSURL *docUrl = [[NSURL alloc]
>   initFileURLWithPath:@"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/34C6FC23-C8BF-407E-AD67-77758BD606E9/Documents/documents/12345678901-1470638583.pdf"]